# How do I view only my phone contacts on my Motorola Milestone X2?

Tags: gmail, motorola-milestone

How may I view only my regular phone contacts and not have them sync to Gmail?

I do not, and do not want to, use Gmail, nor do I want to have my phone contact list connected to it.  I use separate apps for email.  Fine, those work well.

But...my carrier transferred my contacts from my old BlackBerry to my new Milestone X2, but once I registered for a "throwaway" gmail account (only to be able to use the app store) and unchecked the "sync" box, my phone contacts have disappeared.

Is giving Google access to my phone contact list a requirement for using an Android device?  If so, back to the store it goes.  If not, how may I view my regular phone contacts?